# User-edit role setting distinct from wp_capabilities?

Tags: users, user-roles, capabilities

I need find out how `$profileuser->roles` is set.

`wp_capabilities` can hold multiple roles, whereas *user-edit* role caters only for a single role.

Under certain circumstances it is possible for there to be one or more roles in `wp_capabilities` but none set in *user-edit*.

That suggests that there must be another setting used to define *user-edit* role distinct from `wp_capabailities`.

In order to import a large batch of of legacy user data with roles set, I need to understand how/where the *user-edit* setting is stored distinct from `wp_capabilities`.

The particular circumstance is with syncing between WP users and membership type in CiviCrm. The sync uses mapping between WP *user-edit* role setting to Civi Membership type. CiviCrm allows multiple membership types per user.

I am using:

- WP 3.8.1
- Members plugin 0.2.4
- CiviCrm plugin 4.4

Comment: Hi Sven, for clarity of others coming to help, maybe add CiviCRM to title? user-edit not a default wordpress role.

Comment: I thought third-party plugins were off-topic? Don't get me wrong, this question is interesting and I'd like to see some answers. I'm just asking.